# How to Correct MTD in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Table:

Date    Item
1-Aug   Apple
1-Aug   Orange
1-Aug   Banana
2-Aug   Apple
2-Aug   Orange
3-Aug   Apple

There are 2 slicers:
Slicer1: Date: Single Selection
Slicer2: Item: Multiple Selection

DAX: To determine MTD count
TOTALMTD(COUNT(Table['Item']), DATEMTD(ALLSELECTED(Table['Date'])))

Case1: Slicer1: 2-Aug & Slicer2: Apple and Orange

DAX returns 4 (Correct)

Case2: Slicer1: 3-Aug & Slicer2: Apple and Orange

DAX returns 3. Expected output is 5. (3 Apples on 1/2/3Aug and 2 Oranges on 1/2Aug)

Seeking advice here as I am struggling hard throughout the day. How to get the MTD DAX to cater for 2 oranges in the past (1/2 Aug)?

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 tables in my model

1. DimDate(Date, MonthNo)
2. DimFruits(Item)
3. FruitFact(Date, Item)

Measure:

```
MTD Count = CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS('FruitFact'),
                FILTER(ALL('DimDate'),[Date]<=MAX('DimDate'[Date])
                && [MonthNo] = MAX('DimDate'[MonthNo]) ))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, it did not work out as expected as there is date slicer in place. Can you help to modify the proposed DAX?